# Groupby then sum doesn't work when running on large df

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pivot-table

I'm trying to tidy up a long and messy csv file a bit, but my method doesn't seem to work until I tried splitting the raw data into several files. Just wondering if anyone can see what goes wrong here?

The original file looks like this, except there are 600+ rows:

```
Code   Item       Size    Location   Available
DD2    Cap Blue   S       NY         3
DD2    Cap Blue   S       NY         6
DD2    Cap Blue   S       CA         18
DD2    Cap Blue   S       PA         20
DD3    Cap Blue   L       CA         5
DA5    Tee Red    S       NY         1
DA7    Tee White  S       PA         203
DA7    Tee White  S       PA         204
```

I would like to turn it into:

```
Code   Item       Size    Location   Available
DD2    Cap Blue   S       NY         9
                          CA         18
                          PA         20
DD3    Cap Blue   L       CA         5
DA5    Tee Red    S       NY         1
DA7    Tee White  S       PA         407
```

, so that I can then use the pivot_table function to make it tidy.

The method I'm using is

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Code', 'Item', 'Size', 'Location'])['Available'].sum()
print(df2)
```

However, pandas merges the values in 'Available' as the numbers are plain text, i.e. the result looks like

```
Code   Item       Size    Location   Available
DD2    Cap Blue   S       NY         36
                          CA         18
                          PA         20
DD3    Cap Blue   L       CA         5
DA5    Tee Red    S       NY         1
DA7    Tee White  S       PA         203204
```

What I can't get my head around is, if I split the data, say I only take 20 rows out and run the command, it would work perfectly.

I'm very new to python and pandas, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use dtype as part of the CSV load ```pd.read_csv(file,  dtype={"Available":int})```,  also after the sum you may want to do a reset_index like ```df.groupby(['Code', 'Item', 'Size', 'Location'])['Available'].sum().reset_index()```  if you want to access the columns Code, Item, etc.. by name

Comment: Thank you very much. Tried this method too. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data-type of the `Available` column, e.g. by:

```
df2["Available"] = df2["Available"].values.astype(float)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it did work! Still not sure why it would work when I split the data tho lol. Thanks again.